# Postagem de um aplicativo

Tags: android, apk

Como postar um aplicativo tendo como "dono" uma empresa?
Existe uma conta de usuário empresarial? ou é feita por uma conta de alguém e no apk é descrito que o app é de tal empresa?

Answer (score -1):

Vai usar o o nome que estiver na sua conta do Google, se voce aderir ao programa de app com  a sua conta pessoal provavelmente a parte onde mostra o "dono" do app vai ficar com a o seu nome por exemplo `Rodolfo.JJ`